# How to export Pandas DataFrame to HTML but without any formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to export a DF with Pandas to an HTML formatted table, but I don't want any of the default styling that Pandas does to its tables, and would prefer just a bone-stock table. Is there an easy way to do this when using the to_html function?

There isn't really a Minimal Reproducible Example since it is just one line of code, I just want
`html_file = df.to_html()`

to make my HTML file table go from

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
```

to

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
```

Comment: please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to allow others understand your current problem and help you.

Comment: You can just use pandas Styler. `df.style.to_html`. That method setting exclude_styles to True will output a barebones table

Answer (score 0):

For me working remove attributes after generate `html`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1]
    })


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(df.to_html(), features="lxml")
for tag in soup.find_all(True):
    tag.attrs.clear()
```

---

```
print(soup.prettify())
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
      a
     </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>
      0
     </th>
     <td>
      1
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is equivalent to `df.style.to_html(exclude_styles=True)` fwiw